# Limite de solicitações do google maps expira com apenas 1 requisição no laravel

Tags: laravel, google-maps

Ola, estou testando uma API do google maps para meu projeto laravel (https://github.com/farhanwazir/laravelgooglemaps) e quando faço apenas uma requisição do mapa o limite de requisições da API expira, gostaria de saber se alguem ja utilizou essa API no laravel e se tem alguma ideia de por que isso ocorre. Segue o código teste:

```
        $m['center'] = 'Praia Grande, São Paulo';
    $m['zoom']   = '18';
    $m['map_height'] = '500px';
    GMaps::initialize($m);
    $map = GMaps::create_map();
    $user = \App\User::all();
    return view('home',compact('user','map'));
```

código da view:

```
        <div class="row">

        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
            {!! $map['js'] !!}

            {!! $map['html'] !!}
</div>
```

Comment: Você precisa adicionar a chave da api no arquivo "APP_PATH/config/googlemaps.php"

Comment: Eu ja adiconei, eu consigo fazer a primeira requisição, mas da segunda em diante ele diz que já acabaram o numero de requisições diarias, e no site do google ele diz que ja atingiu 100%.